# Почему иногда избегается использования интерфейса или базового класса?

Tags: c#, архитектура

Вот например в `ASP.NET Core` класс, который запускает приложение должен содержать `ConfigureServices` и `Configure`.

Сам этот стартовый класс не имеет никакого контракта в виде интерфейса или абстрактного класса.

Почему сделано именно так? Тут же видно, что использование контракта пригодилось бы.

Comment: скорее всего здесь стремились сделать синглтон, с целью того, что-бы в системе не появилось сразу двух файлов настройки (оно собственно вытекает из логики).

Comment: @Monomax, что-то не вижу взаимосвязи. Ну будет 2 файла настройки, но приложение можно запустить вызвав только один Startup.

Comment: Потому что у методов `ConfigureServices` и `Configure` нет строгой сигнатуры, поэтому вынести интерфейс невозможно в принципе. Эти методы могут принимать любые зависимости, которые будут успешно им потом предоставлены

Comment: @АндрейNOP хм... Вот  оно как... Ну могли бы ввести еще один тип интерфейсов с плавающими параметрами.

Comment: Эмммм, это как?

Comment: @АндрейNOP, не я к тому, что они могли ввести какую-то новую фишку в компилятор, что бы можно было делать контракты на уровне методов, абстрагируясь от конкретных входных параметров.

Comment: А это возможно? Вы захотите чтобы `ConfigureServices` принимал какой-нибудь ваш `IMySuperPuperInterface`, как это предусмотреть? Можно, конечно, было бы попробовать что-то сделать с дженериками, но совсем от исследования сигнатур в рантайме никак не уйти скорее всего, да и выглядело бы это более громоздко скорее всего, поэтому решили сделать так. Но это мои мысли, мотивация разработчиков мне неизвестна.

Comment: @АндрейNOP Не, я к тому, что бы был какой-нибудь контракт по типу "Мне пофигу на сигнатуру, лишь бы был метод с таким именем" и тогда бы компилятор мог бы подсказывать, что такой-то метод ожидает в объекте такой-то метод, а вот сейчас мне никто не запретит не создать обязательный метод и свалиться в рантайме.

Comment: Я думаю, что это противоречит идеологии языка во-первых, а во-вторых, разработчики языка и фреймворка между собой скорее всего никак не пересекаются. Фреймворк построен на соглашениях и вы должны их знать, если хотите им успешно пользоваться, ничего тут не сделаешь, соглашения есть почти в любом фреймворке